# How to set a default scope order with input from multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application has a user model with two integer columns, `:votes` and `:badges`, in addition to the usual `:id` and `:timestamp` columns.

Currently, the default scope for users is:

```
default_scope order: 'users.created_at DESC'
```

How can I update the default scope to order by a ranking algorithm made up of :votes :badges?

My algorithm is:

```
ranking = 2 * votes + badges
```

What is the best way to do this?

I expected to be able to create a method in the model as follows, but this doesn't work

```
def ranking
  2 * self.votes + self.badges
end
```

Do I need to create a `ranking` column in my database?
Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to write

```
default_scope order("votes * 2 + badges")
```

Comment: Thanks @cdesrosiers. How would I go about testing more complex formulas for blog posts such as `(blog.votes - 1)/(Time.now - blog.created_at)/1.hour +2)^1.5`. Is there a way I can define the formula first, then use it in the scope?